# Neo4j 4.1.x access on port 7474

Tags: neo4j

I'm migrating from Neo4j 3.5.x to 4.1.x, although I set dbms.security.auth_enabled=false I can't don't access the database in Safari at the http://localhost:7474/browser address, I get to the Bolt authentication page instead. Similarly request to REST endpoints from javascript fail.

```
http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
```

Is authenticated access now mandatory with Neo4j 4.x?
Thanks

```
# Configuration:

dbms.default_advertised_address=localhost
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false

# HTTP Connector. There can be zero or one HTTP connectors.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474
dbms.connector.http.advertised_address=:7474
```

Comment: Are you putting the data folder in a weird place? I recommend a fresh install of Neo4j, then login with the username=neo4j, password=neo4j, then change the data location if you want.

Comment: @AdrianKeister no, i didn’t change that setting. The data folder is in the neo4j folder. I can access the database using cypher-shell, it’s also working in safari using bolt. Only http and rest aren’t working.